# Create global acl for all models in loopbackjs

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

While using standard acl generator `slc loopback:acl` - it's just creates acls in each model.json file. But I'll add new model and this won't have any acl by default.

I want to have some global acl which applies by default on any exists model but an acl in json file of model should overrides this. Does loopback supports something like this ?

Comment: This is a feature request currently in the pipeline.  Should be tracked here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1003

Comment: Is there any news on this subject? The feature request on Github is closed. Any way to define a global acl for all models of a Loopback app?